# Is there a way to run code once a method has finished?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsarray, afnetworking, uicollectionviewcell

I want to start code once a method is completed. I have a *UICollectionView* which loads an array of images from a server and then adds those images to the ImageView in the cell I create to better explain here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    insightCell *myCell = (insightCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    myCell.tag = [[[objectiveGov n_insights] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]integerValue];
    imgTag = ((UICollectionView *)myCell).tag;
//This is the Method I want to run "ObjectiveGov is the NSObject which has my Method inside "arrayImages" which is separate to the view controller this UICollectionView is in.
    [objectiveGov arrayImages];

//Possible if statement here, that records when the method above is finished.
    myCell.insightImageView.image = [theInsightImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
            return myCell;
        }
```

So once the method `[objectiveGov arrayImages];` is finished I want it to run the `myCell.insightImageView.image`. Is there a way of doing this? I tried creating a NSNotificationCenter that posted at the end of the method but this didn't work because the UICollectionViewCell method initiates when the UICollectionView is allocated. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT** 
ArrayImages Method Code:

```
+(void)arrayImages
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"postArrayImages" object:nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/insights/get/",URL_ROOT]];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[viewInsightViewController imgTag]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:imageString parameters:nil];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        NSDictionary *dictionInsight = [JSON valueForKey:@"results"];
        NSArray *insightArray = [dictionInsight valueForKey:@"images"];
        NSString *fileName = [dictionInsight valueForKey:@"filename"];
        if (fileName == (id) [NSNull null])
        {
//URL incase server file doesnt contain image.
            nineArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.co.uk/images/logo.png"];
        }else {
            nineArray = [insightArray valueForKey:@"96"];
        }
        insightURL = [NSURL URLWithString:nineArray];

         if (insightURL != nil) {
        NSURLRequest *requestImage = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:insightURL];
        AFImageRequestOperation *imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:requestImage imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                                   { 
                                                       if (requestImage != nil) {
                                                           insightImages = image;
                                                           [arrayOfImages addObject:insightImages];                                                      
 }

                                                   } failure:nil];
        [imageOperation start];
         }
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the `arrayImages` method?

Comment: Yeh sure, I've added in the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a block would be perfect for this situation. Change your array images method to something like this so it calls the block passing back the loaded image when afnetworking is done.

```
+ (void)arrayImagesWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completionBlock {
....
       if (insightURL != nil) {
            NSURLRequest *requestImage = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:insightURL];
            AFImageRequestOperation *imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:requestImage imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                    if (requestImage != nil) {

                       insightImages = image;
                       [arrayOfImages addObject:insightImages];

                       // Call the completion block here once we have the loaded image
                       completionBlock(image);
                    }];

               } failure:nil];

            [imageOperation start];
        }
....
}
```

And call it like this in cellForIndexPath:

```
[objectiveGov arrayImagesWithCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *loadedImage) {
    myCell.insightImageView.image = loadedImage;    
}];
```

One last thing, you are calling valueForKey all over the place where you actually want to do objectForKey. (valueForKey would get a property value of the object versus the dictionary method you want, google "key value coding" for more info).

Comment: I've tried this way first as It saves me having to spend my afternoon revising NSCondition. I was just wondering if you might be able to run me through how exactly this works just so I understand the code I'm using, if thats not too much trouble? also I implemented this but It's not running the code within `[objectiveGov arrayImagesWithCompletionBlock:^{`

Comment: Cheers for making the changes makes more sense now. Yep, this works great thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could go with a condition? Let the [objectiveGov arrayImages] return a BOOL = YES when finished.

```
NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition new];
__block BOOL continueThread = NO;

        if ([objectiveGov arrayImages] == YES) {
            continueThread = YES;
            [condition signal];
            [condition unlock];
        } 

while (!continueThread) [condition wait];
```

Don't know if it will work.. Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Oh ok - Yeh; I was looking around and some stuff that might be similar to my issue and conditions did come up actually. I'll try and implement it and get back to you. I've not used NSCondition before so I might be doing a bit of reading before using it :D. Thanks for your help!